# Bounds is not working with Google Places API

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

My 5 mile bounds that I have set around Orlando, FL is not working.  I am not quite sure what I have done incorrectly.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>

function initAutocomplete() {

  //5 mile bounds around orlando, fl 

  var streetLng = -81.43061;
  var streetLat = 28.56683;

  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(parseInt(streetLat), parseInt(streetLng));
  var north = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, 5, 0).lat();
  var east = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, 5, 90).lng();
  var south = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, 5, 180).lat();
  var west = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, 5, -90).lng();
  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(north, east), new google.maps.LatLng(south, west));

    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
        componentRestrictions: { country: "us" }, types: ['address'], bounds: defaultBounds
    });
}

initAutocomplete();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wybsfvLb/2/

Thanks

Comment: The [documentation for this](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) says that *"This instructs the Place Autocomplete service to **prefer** showing results within that circle. Results outside of the defined area may still be displayed."*

Comment: under componentRestrictions, there is a bounds option.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  And the documentation says that is a *hint*, not a mandate.

Answer (score 0):

I had the defaultBounds switched.  The code should look like the following

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(south, west), new google.maps.LatLng(north, east));
```